# Polymer 1.x: How to imperatively (using JS) obtain the value of a custom CSS property?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

In the following example, I have a parent custom element calling a child custom element. The child has a variable `color` CSS property for `p` elements that can be defined in the parent CSS.

In the JS of the child element, I want to read the `--custom-color` value selected at the parent. In this case, the value is `yellow`. Put another way: when the `getCustomColor()` method is run, I want the console log to read "Your custom color is yellow."

What JavaScript do I put in the `getCustomColor()` method to define `var yourColor`?

my-parent-element.html

```
<style>
  my-child-element {
    --custom-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<template>
  <my-child-element></my-child-element>
</template>
```

my-child-element.html

```
<style>
  p {
    color: var(--custom-color);
  }
</style>
<script>
  getCustomColor: function() {
    var yourColor = // What goes here to obtain the correct value of 'yellow'?
    console.log('Your custom color is' + yourColor);
  }
</script>
```

FYI: [This documentation describes the custom style API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-api). But I can't seem to find the reference to what I'm describing in this question.

Comment: Do you have a constraint to add that custom prop within the css?, what about using a `data-` attribute and read it with `.data("custom-color")`. If that is not an option, you could read the `.css()` prop from the element and search for your `--custom-color` prop.... I would definitely use the `data` approach if you have control on how the dome is rendered. BTW, the suggestion is based only on `jquery` and `html` functions / elements. I have not worked with polymer before

Comment: The docs you linked actually mention it...

You just need to check `this.customStyle['--my-property-name']` and it will have the value of the property

Comment: I'll put it as an answer so that it's easier for people searching for this to find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs you linked actually mention it...

You just need to check `this.customStyle['--my-property-name']` and it will have the value of the property

Comment: Also possible with `window.getComputedStyle($0).getPropertyValue('--custom-color')` where `$0` is a reference to a DOM element. Via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36609605/230167

Comment: Ninja'd twice. Today isn't my day. Have upvotes, both of you.

Comment: When I do `var yourColor = this.customStyle['--custom-color']`, I get `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: @abluejelly: Even though I upvoted and accepted this answer, I had to [redo this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38319721/1640892) because I failed to specify that I would like a working example, JSbin. So if you would like to try, I would be happy to provide you with an upvote and [accept your answer to this quetstion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38319721/1640892).

Answer (score 0):

Per comment by @BryanDowning:

```
var s = document.querySelector('p');
var yourColor = window.getComputedStyle(s).getPropertyValue('color');
// Using Polymer syntax, the above line could be written as follows:
var yourColor = s.getComputedStyleValue('color');
```

That sort of works. It returns the current value of the `color` property of the first `p` element.

Comment: Also, [see this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/bavezaciwi/edit?html,output) for a working example of something similar. ... jsbin.com/bavezaciwi/edit?html,output