# Polymer 1.x: Obtaining customStyles property value

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

[Here is my jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kevanicebu/edit?html,console,output).

The `parent-element` sets the value of the `--custom-color` property in the `child-element`. I want to get the value of that property from the JS in the `child-element`.

[Here is the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-api) but I can not find it mentioned anywhere in there how to do this.

Please provide a working example (jsBin) with your answer.

```html
<h4>http://jsbin.com/kevanicebu/edit?html,console,output</h4>
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <style>
    child-element {
      --custom-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <child-element></child-element>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-element',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="child-element">
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: var(--custom-color, green);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <h1 on-tap="showColor">Click Me</h1>
    <p>I want the console to log the <code>--custom-color</code> property (i.e., "blue") when the user clicks above.</p>
    <p>Right now, it reads: "undefined."</p>
    <p>What changes do I make to the <code>showColor()</code> method?</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',
      showColor: function() {
        // What do I need to change in the below line of code?
        console.log(this.customStyle['--custom-color']);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<parent-element></parent-element>
```

Comment: This sounds almost identical to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317155/polymer-1-x-how-to-imperatively-using-js-obtain-the-value-of-a-custom-css-pro) you asked a few hours ago and for which you accepted an answer. Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: @tony19: It's my fault that I did not request a working example in my previous question. So I did not really solve my problem, although the answer to that question was technically correct. If you look at the jsBin included in this question, I think it will be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is overwritten by the parent, I don't think you can get the original out (default) value. This is how you get the value at the time of running `this.getComputedStyleValue('--custom-color')`

```html
<h4>http://jsbin.com/kevanicebu/edit?html,console,output</h4>
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <style>
    child-element {
      --custom-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <child-element></child-element>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-element',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="child-element">
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: var(--custom-color, green);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <h1 on-tap="showColor">Click Me</h1>
    <p>I want the console to log the <code>--custom-color</code> property (i.e., "blue") when the user clicks above.</p>
    <p>Right now, it reads: "undefined."</p>
    <p>What changes do I make to the <code>showColor()</code> method?</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',
      showColor: function() {
        // What do I need to change in the below line of code?
        console.log(this.getComputedStyleValue('--custom-color'));
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<parent-element></parent-element>
```