# Custom css properties or partial css-variables shim

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to be able to define some non-standard properties inside my CSS classes which can then be picked up by my javascript at runtime in exactly the same way and with the same precedence as standard ones using Window.getComputedStyle() or jQuery.css().

This is to allow flexible theming of items such as  gauge needle paths, radial scale extents etc, in some SVG-based gauges in a dashboard.

This facility is provided by the css-variables specification but is currently only implemented in firefox:
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/

I don't need the full functionality of the css-variables specification since the variables only need to be read by my JavaScript code, not by standard css properties.

Can anybody suggest a shim or a means of implementing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing this through CSS, can you not make use of the `data-*` attributes HTML has to offer?

Comment: Yes I can but it doesn't really do what I want. I'd like some clean, flexible theming with everything to do with look and feel captured in one place (ie classes). Also data-* attributes don't cascade in the same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom CSS properties, why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274350/custom-css-properties-why-not)

Comment: The question suggested as a duplicate gives some intriguing if ugly hacks to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Myth mimics the CSS spec syntax-wise, but unfortunately the values don't obey the cascade. http://www.myth.io/

Comment: @torazaburo I can live without the cascade but need to access the variables from my runtime javascript code. Will Myth let me do that? I couldn't see how.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a preprocessor CSS library to do the work you looking for: i personally suggest **[SASS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-sass)**, (along with [GRUNT JS](http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/)) that use variables and **much more**.

If you've never had to deal with these new tools, at first they seems little hard, but it take a few attempts to use to get familiar with: so, in this [article](http://alistapart.com/article/why-sass)  you shall have a full explanation how SASS can boost your development workflow.

Comment: Preprocessing (using SASS or LESS) will definitely not work. I need to pick up the variables at run time.