# Prevent downloading background-image when parent is hidden and css of child is read

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

As we already known to prevent loading element `background-image` it's parent must be hidden using `display:none`.

This method works great on FF and Chrome.

On Chrome when you read any `.child` div css property using jquery `.css()` (`getComputedStyle`) method, image will start to download.
Element is still hidden so it shouldn't. 
Firefox is not downloading.

I've also tested it on Safari 5.1 and it's the same, it starts to download image, so possibly it is webkit browser behaviour :(

**I've created test case: http://jsfiddle.net/zxLyttc3/1/embedded/result/**

1. open it in chrome
2. open developer tools and goto NETWORK tab,
3. reload page, as you can see there is no `example_image.png` file so background-image is not loaded
4. click on a button, that will simply read css width value from `.child` element
5. `example_image.png` started to download

Has any one know any (hacky) solution to read css value but prevent downloading `background-image`?

I was thinking to store `background-image` in other css property like `counter-reset`, see here "[custom-css-properties-why-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274350/custom-css-properties-why-not)" but it requires to run js loop every time when my css classes changes to update `background-image` style on elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `background-image` dynamically at the same time you make `.parent` visible.